# Как импортировать класс TypeScript

Tags: typescript, импорт

Имеются два класса.

animal.ts

```
export type AnimalColor = string | number

export class Animal {
    name: string
    color: AnimalColor

    constructor(name: string, color: AnimalColor){
        this.name = name
        this.color = color
    }

    public printData(){
        console.log(this.name, this.color);
    }
}
```

dog.ts

```
import { Animal, AnimalColor } from "./animal"

export class Dog extends Animal{
    constructor(name){
        super(name, 'black')
    }
}
```

Также имеется главный файл, в котором я использую один класс: 
main.ts

```
import {Dog} from './dog'

var dog = new Dog('hello');
dog.printData();
```

Проблема в том, когда я компилирую файл main.ts и подключаю скомпилированный js файл на страницу, появляется ошибка

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at main.js:1:1)".

Пробовал ставить в теге script атрибут type со значением module, запускать локальный сервер, но ничего не помогло получить результат. Как можно исправить эту проблему?
Файл tsconfig не использую.

Компилирую следующим образом: `tsc main.ts -t es2015 -outDir source`

Comment: какие настройки в tsconfig? как именно собираешь?

Comment: Файл tsconfig не использую. Компилирую следующим образом: tsc main.ts -t es2015 -outDir source

Comment: добавь это все в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: Разве ошибка не говорит о том, что js скрипт использующий import не имеет тип модуля? `<script src="..." type="module">`

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло.

Comment: Появлялась ошибка про CORS политику, но почитав в интернете понял, что дело в сервере. Запустил локальный сервер (через расширение Live Server), и словил ошибку net::ERR_ABORTED на dog.js и animal.js, хотя пути указаны верно и все файлы присутствуют.